# Why am I receiving an "invalid context" error in the following Core Graphics code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have the following drawing code:

```
    static int i=10;
    int x;
    int y;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    // Drawing code.
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    CGFloat colour[4] = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, colour);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    NSLog(@"fired...");
    int xline[340] = {30,80,80,20};     
    int yline[340] = {40,40,20,20};
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x, y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c,x2,y2);
    //CGContextStrokePath(c);    
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        x2 = xline[j];
        y2 = yline[j];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x2, y2);
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }    
    CGContextStrokePath(c); 
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    i++;
```

However, when it runs, I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Wed Aug 10 11:13:05 Mac-Minis-Mac-mini.local LineDraw[1880] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

What could cause these errors and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I can not believe that some one voted this question for closing...

Answer (score 8):

Unless you have this code in the `drawRect:` method of a `UIView` subclass or have specifically pushed a graphics context onto the stack (e.g. by using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`), `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `NULL`.

All the drawing functions require a graphics context.

Comment: In my particular example, I start with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` but, if it matters, I'm doing this on a thread (and there may be other threads trying to do similar drawing.)  So it works correctly for the first several dozen images, then fails on the next one.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information about how draw rectangle line etc, then check [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) in which you will get whole information.